# Command for table with label

Tags: tables, macros, captions

How can I create a command for a 2 tables with a label on top and a command for the options below? example of what i am saying is:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code which you have tried so far?

Comment: I am actually trying to modify my code and it turns out like this :P                              \documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|p{1.7cm}|}
  \hline
Good & Bad \\hline
   \  \  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}

Comment: @kayla See my updated answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

The following is a simple way of achieving what you want. I will add further clarification if you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  % http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{lipsum,tabularx,array} % http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol,enumitem}     % enables multicolumns and custom enumeration

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
%
Write the following in its proper places.\\[2ex]
% This defines the new column type to have the words Good and Bad centered to fit what the OP wants. 
% Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to have it in a single table. Probably a using \multicolumn might work.
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{CC}
Good & Bad
\end{tabularx}
%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
  & \\[5cm] % Increase or decrease the table height
\hline
\end{tabularx}
% Declare the options here
\begin{multicols}{5}
\begin{itemize}[label=$-$]
\item Smoking
\item Drinking liquor
\item Exercise
\item Studying
\item Fighting
\item Vegetables
\item Crying
\item Sitting
\item Lying
\item Honest
\item Brave
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Can you figure it out from here? That is, how to create the commands?

---

Am leaving the above as a reference for you to compare the definitions of the commands and the application of options to achieve the results:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}    % http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{lipsum,tabularx,array}   % http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol,enumitem,tikz}  % TiKZ offers the \foreach command used below.
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}%

% Defining the table with 3 options: 2 for table headers and one for the desired height
% for the table.
\newcommand{\tableclassification}[3]{%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{CC}
#1 & #2
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
  & \\[#3] % Increase or decrease the table height
\hline
\end{tabularx}
}

% Offers a simple command to get the options for the table. The first option controls the
% controls the number of columns to be used and the last controls the data or options.
\newcommand{\tableoptions}[2]{%
\begin{multicols}{#1}
\begin{itemize}[label=$-$]
\foreach \tabopt in {#2}
{%
\item \tabopt%
}
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
}

\begin{document}
\tableclassification{Good}{Bad}{5cm}
\tableoptions{5}{Smoking, Drinking Liquor, Exercise, Studying, Fighting, Vegetables, Crying, Sitting, Lying, Honest, Brave}
\end{document}
```